# Переклад чи транслітерація власних назв в офіційних документах?

Tags: переклад, from-english, власні-назви

Зіткнулась з необхідністю перекласти власну назву "***American Medical Writers Association***" **в офіційних документах**. 
Вважаю, що правильним перекладом буде "***Американська спілка медичних письменників***".
Але виникли сумніви, чи взагалі слід перекладати, можливо, застосувати правила транслітерації натомість?

Сумніви появились, оскільки [тут](https://studfiles.net/preview/1588475/page:3/) написано таке:

> У практиці перекладу усталеним вже є правило, згідно за яким назви
>   громадських організацій перекладаються повністю, причому якомога
>   ближ­че до оригіналу, якщо це точно передає значення назви та не
>   порушує норм мови перекладу: International Society of General Research
>   - Міжнародне това­риство фундаментальних досліджень

Зауважу на фразі "усталеним є правило", тобто це радше внаслідок постійної повторюваності,  а не регламентоване певними нормами, чи правильно я розумію?

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%92%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%96%D1%97:%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F_%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B2_%D1%96%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F) міститься така інформація:

> В українській мові діють три принципи передачі іншомовних назв: 1)
>   транскрипція, 2) етимологія, 3) традиція передачі, якщо є. ... Назви
>   не перекладаються!

*У зв`язку з цим виникає питання: перекладати власну назву (American Medical Writers Association) чи застосовувати правила транслітерації?*

Comment: «American Medical Writers Association» — це не та назва, яку треба транскрибувати («Америкен Медикал Врайтерз Асовшієйшен»). А от «Microsoft» варто залишити Майкрософтом (а не перекладати як «Мікром'який»). Але де межа — мені сказати важко.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Скористаємося в цьому випадку способом кальки, щоб утворити переклад

**Асоціація американських медичних письменників**

або

**Американська асоціація медичних письменників**

> Калькування можна застосовувати тільки тоді, коли утворений таким
>   чином перекладний відповідник не порушує норми вживання і
>   сполучуваності слів в українській мові.

[Педан М. С. ОСОБЛИВОСТІ ПЕРЕКЛАДУ ВЛАСНИХ НАЗВ В ХУДОЖНІХ ТВОРАХ](http://confcontact.com/2013_04_17/25_Pedan.htm)

Назва з чотирьох слів важко сприйматиметься в транслітерації. До всього, кожне слово має відповідник в нашій мові, жодне не вжито метафорично, жодне не відноситься до унікальних назв чи оказіоналізмів. Тому вибір кальки вмотивований.